# How to check if a sub-array contains all elements of another array javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

I have an array of projects called `rawProjects` which looks like this:

```
rawProjects = [
    {
         id: 1,
         name: "proj1",
         technology: [
             0: {id: 21, project_id: 1,name: "java"},
             1: {id: 22, project_id: 1,name: "c++"}
          ]
    },
    {
         id: 2,
         name: "proj2",
         technology: [
             0: {id: 23, project_id: 2,name: "sql"},
             1: {id: 24, project_id: 2,name: "python"},
             2: {id: 25, project_id: 2,name: "react"}

         ]
    }
]
```

I also have an array of technology called `tempTags`  which contains the technologies that the user enters to search from. So far I have been able to do the `OR` case where in I return the projects which contain either of the technologies mentioned by the user using:

```
const filteredProjects = rawProjects.filter(x => x.technology.some(g => tempArr.includes(g.name)))
```

So for example if `tempTags = [sql, c++]` both projects will be returned.

How do I implement the `AND` case such that only projects that contain both of these technologies are returned. Eg if `tempTags = [java, c++]` , only the first project will be returned. If `tempTags = [sql, c++]`, nothing will be returned?

Comment: `.every` and `.includes` are the two array functions you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the `tempTags` and check that `.every` one of them is included:

```js
const rawProjects = [
    {
         id: 1,
         name: "proj1",
         technology: [
             {id: 21, project_id: 1,name: "java"},
             {id: 22, project_id: 1,name: "c++"}
          ]
    },
    {
         id: 2,
         name: "proj2",
         technology: [
             {id: 23, project_id: 2,name: "sql"},
             {id: 24, project_id: 2,name: "python"},
             {id: 25, project_id: 2,name: "react"}

         ]
    }
]

const tempTags = ['java', 'c++'];
const filtered = rawProjects.filter(
  p => {
    const techNames = p.technology.map(({ name }) => name);
    return tempTags.every(
      tag => techNames.includes(tag)
    );
  }
);
console.log(filtered);
```

You'll also need to fix your syntax: arrays do not have key-value pairs, only values. (Remove the `0:`, `1:`, etc), and make sure to put commas in between array values (there should be a comma after `"python"}`)